# class bind not binding 'this'

Tags: javascript, closures, jsx, phaser-framework

I have a method that creates an object in a Class.
The method should use an Object (declared inside the constructor) in its same Class when called.
In another Class I'm creating an object by calling the previously mentioned method, but it seems that it doesn't recognize its constructor object even after I bind the method in the same constructor.

**code:**

```
//Here I call the method createSprite

import Loader from '../sprites/loader'

export default class extends Phaser.State {
  init () {
    this.SpriteLoader = new Loader()
  }
  preload () {
    this.game.add.image(0, 0, 'background')
  }
  create () {
    console.log(this.SpriteLoader.oSprites) //prints the object
    let naruto = new this.SpriteLoader.createSprite({game: this.game, x: 50, y: 50, asset: 'naruto'})
  }
}
```

Here is the method class:

```
import NarutoSprite from './naruto/naruto'

export default class extends Phaser.State {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.oSprites = {
      oSpritesClass: {
        'naruto': NarutoSprite
      }
    }
    this.createSprite = this.createSprite.bind(this)
  }
  createSprite (prop) {
    // "this" refers to this same createSprite function when 
    //  called from another class

    return this.oSprites.oSpritesClass[prop.asset]({ game: prop.game, x: prop.x, y: prop.y, asset: prop.asset })
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling an instance method with the word `new` (if nothing else, it's terribly confusing) - `new this.SpriteLoader.createSprite`? I'm assuming the compiled code (not the raw ES6) has some references (e.g. `_this`'s) in it that thwarts whatever it is you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Indeed you solved my problam :) I used the 'new' keyword in the wrong place wich couse the bind to be ignored thanks